# Nothing in storyboard is appearing in the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5.0.1

Last night I was using storyboard and running the app in simulator and everything was running fine. Today I woke up and made some edits to the storyboard and tried to run them and nothing changed from the old storyboard in simulator. Any image or button I moved remained the same when simulator opened. I ran clean/build/run and nothing changed.

Comment: Be careful you aren't changing a iphone specific storyboard and running on an ipad simulator.  If not try deleting the app from the simulator, close and reopen xcode clean / rebuild... sometimes xcode gets into weird states where stuff like this happens.

Comment: Also, as a last resort, delete the app from the simulator. Same thing can happen on a device.

Comment: Thanks ill try this but in getting a SIGBRT error now

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. Xcode 5.1.1 Mavericks

I tried doing a clean build, restarting Xcode - neither worked.

Here's what did work:

1) I reset the Simulator.

-- Ran again - got an error "No storyboard named 'Mainboard' found" (even though it was obviously RIGHT there)

2) I renamed my storyboard, e.g. "M1ainboard"

3) Then renamed it back, e.g. "Mainboard"

-- Ran again - worked fine, changes are showing up!